# How can i separate tuples in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

How can i merge a list of tuples without repeating any items in those tuples ?

for example :

from the list [("a","b"),("c,"d"),("a","b)], it should return ["a","b","c","d"]

---

So i get this error message with that code:

```
No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of `nub'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
  merge :: [(a0, a0)] -> [a0] (bound at P.hs:9:1)
Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
              or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  instance Eq () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
  instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
  ...plus 22 others
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `nub'
In the expression: nub . mergeTuples
In an equation for `merge':
    merge
      = nub . mergeTuples
      where
          mergeTuples = foldr (\ (a, b) r -> a : b : r) []
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 4):

Let's separate this out, first, merge the tuples

```
mergeTuples :: [(a, a)] -> [a]
mergeTuples = concatMap (\(a, b) -> [a, b]) -- Thanks Chuck
-- mergeTuples = foldr (\(a, b) r -> a : b : r) []
```

and then we can use `nub` to make it unique

```
merge :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [a]
merge = nub . mergeTuples
```

If you want this to all be together

```
merge = nub . mergeTuples
  where mergeTuples = concatMap (\(a, b) -> [a, b])
```

Or if you want to smash it really together (don't do this)

```
merge [] = []
merge ((a, b) : r) = a : b : filter (\x -> x /= a && x /= b) (merge r)
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it all in one function ?

Comment: @dcarou Sure, define `mergeTuple` in a where clause

Comment: how would i do that ? and i cannot get this code to work with the example above, it simply does not compile

Comment: @dcarou What is the error message?  Telling us that it doesn't compile doesn't tell us _why_ it doesn't compile

Comment: @dcarou Sorry, I've updated the code and added a type signature, that'll amke it work

Comment: Just a nitpick, but a think a map would be more natural than a fold here — `mergeTuples = concatMap (\(a,b) -> [a, b])`

Comment: The "smashed" version of `merge` does not generate the same result for `[("a","a")]` as the other versions.